# Why is there Portugese language on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

There are many choices on how to tell me that this is your model.

- our model,
- notre modèle
- nuestro modelo
- nosso modelo
- unser Modell
- 011011110111010101110010001000000110110101101111011001000110010101101100

> [image]

Why is there Portuguese language in my help center ?
Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m

Comment: At http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta you mean? Shows just 'our model' for me. But perhaps it is based on the language settings of your browser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I went back it and it now show our model. Weird.. And no. my browser settings aren't set to protuguese.

Comment: The dev team *is* working on localization, specifically so that the Portuguese Stack Overflow site can launch. Someone most likely tripped up and pushed the wrong button somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I like the though of that.

Comment: We are looking into this - might be some shared caching somewhere, though this particular occurrence is rather strange. And yep, we just launched the private beta of the Portuguese SO.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the info.
Alos, how is this off topic.

Comment: @Oded As in an internal, SE-team beta, or a normal-user private beta?

Comment: @UndotheSnowman - normal private beta. It will probably remain that way for a while - a bunch of visual bugs and missed localization bits.

Comment: Caching, it's always caching. No, I mean, localization, it's always localization. No, I mean, Localização, é sempre a localização.

Comment: @Chris this is a fixed bug, if we close this we can also close virtually all fixed bugs.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - indeed we could. However, if you notice there three other people who voted to close the question. I could have left it but I'm guessing that two other regular users would have also voted to close.

Comment: @ChrisF Peer pressure :P

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd - not really, but the question was well on it's way to being closed by the time I came across it.

Comment: @ChrisF I know I was just kidding.

Comment: @ChrisF so as a mod you could close and reopen if you share my opinion. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I see no need to reverse my decision.

Comment: @ChrisF: I prematurely voted to close as 'not reproducible'. I should have retracted it when the bug was confirmed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a translation caching issue - it's been ported to much more recent mechanisms that are both optimized and respect proper cache rules.  A build with this fix went live earlier today.