# My question is On-Hold but Status-Completed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, meta, off-topic

I just want to make sure.

[My question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211131/why-is-there-portugese-language-on-meta) was put on hold after having a status-completed tag.
Yes I know, chances are it is not really possible to reproduce but it was a known issue so I guess it is good that it was pointed out no ?

I mean... **If the bug was fixed, off course it is not possible to reproduce it**.

Was it off topic or not ?

Comment: It is kindof weird, fixed bugs aren't usually closed

Comment: The explanation is in the close reason message: `It can no longer be reproduced`. So it was perfectly OK to ask, but also perfectly OK to  close. I agree handling this under the "off-topic" heading is weird, though.

Comment: I think closing is appropriate when the issue can no longer be reproduced due to changes that weren't specifically meant to fix that issue. Perhaps tagging it as status-complete was incorrect in this case?

Comment: @Stijn so we need to remove the tag and close at least half the fixed bug reports here on Meta. After being fixed, 100% of the bugs can't be reproduced anyway otherwise it means they were not fixed.

Comment: Probably people who voted to close could not reproduce it at no point in time - common problem with caching issues.

Comment: @Mołot Probably but still this shouldn't show up in the `Off-Topic` section.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Should that close reason exist at all then?

Comment: Well, "cannot be reproduced" **is offtopic** on meta, and I think it was discussed already if it's right or wrong. But that's the way it is.

Comment: @Stijn of course, e.g. old bugs about things that does not exist anymore (envelope, faq pages, old top bar and more)

Comment: @Mołot "I tried to access stack overflow and a cat jumped out of my computer" would reasonably be `off topic--> It can no longer be reproduced`. That sort of thing is off topic. But things that were fixed after the bug report seem on topic

Comment: @RichardTingle But my guess was that first votes was cast before it was fixed. Cache glitches often can't be easily reproduced even before they are fixed.

Comment: @Mołot The question was closed two hours after the answer arrived. But yes, I imagine the first votes arrived before that.

Comment: @Duncan well this post has my upvote and I think people should no longer vote to close when it was confirmed (and solved). Unless in reality it was fixed before it was even posted.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, it's closed as "off topic" because meta has a custom close reason for "cannot be reproduced", and custom close reasons are designed so that they're all in the off topic category.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd I'm responding to this: "Probably but still this shouldn't show up in the Off-Topic section." As already mentioned in the comments and made obvious by the custom reason, no repro items are close targets. Why would I bother covering the same ground again?

Comment: Please mark this status-completed.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the question carefully, it seems you noticed the symptom of an issue that had been fixed earlier in the day. I guess only caching problems can behave like that.

Arguably, your question shouldn't have been tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) since nothing was altered. However, I suspect this is often done out of politeness by the relevant developer.

I would say the tagging is the error here. A forgiveable one, since it's clearly good-natured. But your problem could not be reproduced (not even by yourself after the initial observation) and a developer confirmed the issue was already fixed.

Comment: The answer states that there was indeed an issue that was fixed in a recent change. The use of [status-completed] is probably OK.